# CSS issue with background color in ::after

Tags: html, css

I use the following HTML/CSS code to make a chat bubble:

```css
body {background-color: red}

.message-sent {
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:white;
    background:#0B93F6;
    border-radius:25px;
    float: right;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.message-sent-last::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:-7px;
  height:20px;
  border-right:20px solid #0B93F6;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(0, -2px);
}

.message-sent-last::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:-56px;
  width:26px;
  height:20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-sent message-sent-last">
  Hey there! What's up?
</div>
```

But the problem is in the last line of the CSS in which I am forced to repeat the background color, otherwise, the bubble will break. Please, check this out:

```css
body {background-color: red}

.message-sent {
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:white;
    background:#0B93F6;
    border-radius:25px;
    float: right;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.message-sent-last::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:-7px;
  height:20px;
  border-right:20px solid #0B93F6;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(0, -2px);
}

.message-sent-last::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:-56px;
  width:26px;
  height:20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-sent message-sent-last">
  Hey there! What's up?
</div>
```

I would like to not repeat the background color of the page since the snippet will be used in several places with different background colors. I've tried with transparent and inherit but none worked out.

This is how the second snipped looks like:

[image: demonstration]

I've tested in Chrome and FF under Ubuntu.

What do you think?

Comment: didn't take time to read your question but on my FF, both snippets look just the same

Comment: @Kaiido I tested in FF and Chrome under Ubuntu. Added an image to the original question showing how the second snipped looks like.

Comment: This is how both look like on my FF48 on mac : http://i.stack.imgur.com/cuyIY.png

Comment: It looks as the picture you posted for me. First of all do you know how ::after works in your particular case? adding that div with the same color of the background is the actual trick that creates the bubble's tail

Comment: yes, and it should look like this [link](http://i.imgur.com/a82eY85.png) without needing to specify background: red in ::after

Comment: I think but I might be wrong, that you cannot achieve that without setting the background of the after div to the same color of the body

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since it is fundamental for the creation of the bubble to assign the same color of the background to the div I would suggest to use a variable, so when the color of the body changes even the color of the div::after will change:

add at the top of your css file:

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: red;
}
```

in your body element:

```
body {background-color: var(--main-bg-color);}
```

and div:

```
.message-sent-last::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:-40px;
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-30px, -2px);
  background: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

This allows you to change it on root and making the change effective on both elements.

Please note that it will not work on IE though.